# Google Maps. Генерирование случайного расположения маркеров

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Я сейчас генерирую рандомно n-нное кол-во маркеров в некотором радиусе на картах. Но я не могу контролировать расстояние, которое получается, если пробежать по маркерам по порядку. Может кто подсказать рациональный алгоритм генерирования маркеров с заданным расстоянием?

Сейчас я просто генерирую рандомную точку не учитывая предыдущие. Можно прекращать генерировать, если общее расстояние между всеми маркерами превышает заданное. Но хочу что бы, например, на 10 км было 10 маркеров, которые расположены рандомно (т.е. расстояние между каждым не 1 км :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вам подойдет такое решение:

Сначала берем заданное расстояние и делим его на N частей, каждая из которых имеет случайный размер, но при этом не превышает заданное значение:

```
public static Random r = new Random();

   public static int[] divide(int number, int number_of_parts) {
      HashSet<Integer> uniqueInts = new HashSet<Integer>();
      uniqueInts.add(0);
      uniqueInts.add(number);
      int array_size = number_of_parts + 1;
      while (uniqueInts.size() < array_size) {
         uniqueInts.add(1 + r.nextInt(number - 1));
      }
      Integer[] dividers = uniqueInts.toArray(new Integer[array_size]);
      Arrays.sort(dividers);
      int[] results = new int[number_of_parts];
      for(int i = 1, j = 0; i < dividers.length; ++i, ++j) {
         results[j] = dividers[i] - dividers[j];
      }
      return results;
   }
```

Потом используем значение из результата предыдущей функции(prevPointDevideValue):

```
x = prevPoint.x + prevPointDevideValue * Math.cos(rnd)
y = prevPoint.y + prevPointDevideValue  * Math.sin(rnd)
```

Comment: вроде то,что нужно)) по поводу последнего - я беру начальные координаты + часть расстояния, а какой диапазон для rnd значения?

Comment: @itslayo случайный угол